# CreatePredictor at AWS Forecast disregards "ForecastDimensions"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, dimension, forecast

I defined a TARGET dataset with 4 attributes (item_id, store, date, demand) and need to forecast each item per day per shop. The model trains well, but when casting a prediction, the aws forecast service aggregates all items per day with disregards to the store attribute.

According to the Developer Guide, additional dimensions are taken into account if they are described in the TARGET dataset. This does not work for me.

[AWS Forecast Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/forecast/latest/dg/forecast.dg.pdf)

See the documentary: ForecastDimensions

> If you want the sales forecast for each item by store, you would
>   specify store_id as the dimension. All forecast dimensions specified
>   in the TARGET_TIME_SERIES dataset **don't need to be specified** in
>   the CreatePredictor request

This is my schema of the TARGET dataset:

```
ts_schema_val = [{"AttributeName": "item_id", "AttributeType": "string"},
                 {"AttributeName": "store", "AttributeType": "string"},
                 {"AttributeName": "timestamp", "AttributeType": "timestamp"},
                 {"AttributeName": "demand", "AttributeType": "float"}]
```

As soon as I create a forecast, the dimension "store" is missing in the predictions and items **are not grouped** by store.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to specify "store" in the CreatePredictor.FeaturizationConfig.ForecastDimensions.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/forecast/latest/dg/API_FeaturizationConfig.html#forecast-Type-FeaturizationConfig-ForecastDimensions

Comment: I think "All forecast dimensions specified in the TARGET_TIME_SERIES dataset don't need to be specified in the CreatePredictor request." means that if you dont put store in the forecast dimensions from TARGET_TIME_SERIES, it will be aggregated by item and will lose store granularity.